# Is it appropriate to put the Bridge on a timeout in order to stop an argument?

Tags: discussion, chat

The topic of discussion in the chatroom is VERY OFTEN not one of the topics listed in the room description.  I can see how Arda was being a little difficult to talk to, but what the hell, you don't just FREEZE the room and tell him not to talk about it any more, that's just *dumb*.

Comment: By the way, once you cool down, it'd be nice if you could rephrase this as a question. _ducks_

Comment: For those of us who are no longer participating in chat, mind clarifying?

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7191466#7191466

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Thank you. Entirely uncalled for and unsurprising, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 12):

Often times, if left unchecked arguments on chat can become:

- Long winded
- Not constructive
- Ugly for everyone involved
- Circular
- Argued for the argument's sake

This isn't the first time I have frozen the Bridge for one minute in the hope to cool down the atmosphere and return to more normal activity. Last time, the argument was about Lara Croft and her "rape scene" that actually even is not part of the game to begin with. Feedback on that from the community was overwhelmingly positive.

Arda was asked by multiple people to drop the argument. He didn't, so I froze the room for a minute. He quit as a result. That's unfortunate, but it's the way it is. That's why it happened, and not just because he disagreed.

[This is what happens when people just keep arguing at each other and are left unchecked.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/6393/2012/11/10) Those two guys went back and forth at each other for *24 days*, eventually flagging each other on messages about *standards for smileys and the existance thereof*.

I'm sure we don't want any of this crap in the Bridge.

Comment: Just an FYI, let this be my final post on this site, this is not an isolated incident. You have abused your moderator powers time and time again. I don't know if you have some kind of grudge against me or whether you just have faulty judgement, but I am no longer willing to wait for your next mistake.

Comment: Okay, I agree with the time out being used to calm down, but you can't tell someone what they can or can't discuss in the chat.  If you really don't want to be involved in it, don't reply to him.  Gah, you two were both acting like children in that 'discussion'.

Comment: As for Arda's reason why he quit: moderators acting on their whim rather than community guidelines. I've been enforcing policies I've disagreed with for _years_ without failure*. Arda maybe forgot moderators are human exception handlers; if every our action _was_ guided by rules, we could very well be replaced by a very small bash script without loss. Moderators _are_ asked to make judgement calls. That's what I'm here to do.

Comment: @GnomeSlice The issue here is that Arda was told to bring the topic to meta and he noted that he had no intentions of contributing to the site.  By continuing to discuss it in chat, he was being disruptive.

Comment: @ArdaXi I suggest you distance yourself from the argument for a moment and ask yourself if I really did do what I did today in your spite. I think I didn't. Again, best of luck in your future endeavours.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Yeah, they're *both* acting like children, as I said above.  Come on guys, suck it up and deal with each other like adults!

Comment: @GnomeSlice badp asked for it to be moved to meta.  I'm not sure how he could have handled it better after that point.

Comment: @badp I did that the last dozen times. I'm done. Like I said, I don't know whether it was out of spite or just bad judgement, but to me, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @GnomeSlice Arda, by his own admission, __does not wish to contribute to this site__.  For that reason, I don't think he should be causing a fuss over what is and is not acceptable on this site  __in chat__.  I have nothing against Arda.  Hell, I like Arda.  I like getting into arguments for the sake of arguing.  But I'm not going to disrupt chat with it.

Comment: I just checked the chat briefly and only want to say that mods can/should indeed act on clear cases of copyright infringement, deferring to the community team in less clear cases: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114919/154510